# Which swt/jface control to use for writing telnet in eclipse rcp?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, telnet

I have to write a telnet in eclipse rcp. So can anybody tell me which control should i use?

here control is for eg: swt.Text, swt.StyledText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on many things. If you want to allow for any form of formatting in the output - like support vt100 - then a `StyledText` control is good. If you want to keep it as simple as possible, I would probably use a `Text` for the current input, and a multi-line `Text` for the output.

If you have more freedom in your RCP application, consider adding the `Console` view to the application. This will give a very polished way of adding telnet support...

Comment: I have some extra features like eclipse fieldassist which I think is not working in Console view, so I think StyledText will be better solution for that

Comment: The Console view is in fact based on a StyledText - and you have full access to the control...

Comment: Okk, thanks for your reply. Can you plz suggest me any source which can help me in writing telnet in rcp application